# Validate Separate Date Fields

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Background:
I have 3 separate input fields DD, MM and YYYY for date , month and year respectively. 
I have done a simple if then else to validate if DD > 31 show error message, if MM > 12 show error message and if YYYY > **current year** [ **current year** i fetched using new Date().getFullYear(); ].

Problem:
After a user finishes entering all these three fields, if the date exceeds current date. I want an error message to be shown saying Date of Birth cannot be greater than current date.

Eg: Today is DD:14 MM:03 YYYY:2016. If someone enters DD:12 MM:04 YYYY:2016, error must come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a date object using [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
var date1 = new Date(year, month, date); //all three year, month and date coming from separate fields
```

creata an instance of today's date

```
var dateToday = new Date();
```

Now check their millisecond value

```
if (date1.getTime() > dateToday.getTime())
{
   //date1 is greater than today
}
```

Comment: Are these year month and date inside new Date()  global variables?